# Search multi words in a single search iOS swift using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, nspredicate

I want to search a list by typing multi words from the detailed list.
e.g,
in a claim request list there are different type of lables such as amount, requestor name, request name and nos also. So i want to search anything from this label so that i can able to find the exact request.

[image: In this image i have made a sample list having type, requestor, reg no and amount. I want to search the list by typing multi words using these params.]

Comment: Show us your tried?

Comment: use `filter` is easier than `NSPredicate`

Comment: Actually i have followed : (http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/tableview-search-in-swift) this one for single search. But unable to find multiwords.

Comment: How to write the syntax for nspredicate to search these below in search bar        

requestTypeArr = []
requestorEmployeeArr = []
regNoArr = []
amountOrDaysArr = []

Comment: you use 5 array for cell label?

Comment: use array of dictionary it is easy to optimize,,

Answer (score 1):

```
var predicateList = [NSPredicate]()

let words = filterText.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

for word in words{

 if count(word)==0{
       continue
 }

 let RequestTypeArray = NSPredicate(format: "RequestType contains[c] %@", word)
 let RequestEmployeeArray = NSPredicate(format: "RequestorEmployee contains[c] %@", word)
 let RegesterNumberArray = NSPredicate(format: "ReqNo contains[c] %@", word)
 let AmountOrDaysArray = NSPredicate(format: "AmountOrDays contains[c] %@", word)

 let orCompoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate,departmentPredicate,jobTitlePredicate])

 predicateList.append(orCompoundPredicate)
}

  request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type:    NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: predicateList)
```

Comment: When i write the above code

let words = filterText.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

for word in words{

 if count(word)==0{
       continue

I get an error :::   Use of unresolved identifier"filtertext"

Comment: func filterTableViewForEnterText(searchText: String) {  // this searchText used as filterText }

Comment: let words = filterText.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")    

i am getting error  value of type '(String) -> ()' has no member 'componentsSeparatedByString'

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer was helpful to you..

```
let addresspredicate = NSPredicate(format: "address_name contains[c] %@",searchText)
    let accnopredicate = NSPredicate(format: "acc_no contains[c] %@",searchText)
    let propertytype = NSPredicate(format: "property_type contains[c] %@",searchText)
    let subpropertytypoe = NSPredicate(format: "subproperty_type contains[c] %@",searchText)

    let predicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .or, subpredicates: [addresspredicate,accnopredicate,propertytype,subpropertytypoe])
    filteredProperty = (propertyArray as Array).filter { predicateCompound.evaluate(with: $0) };
    print("filteredProperty = ,\(filteredProperty)")
```